# Allowing a Route to Access Data from a Collection with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes, pdfkit

I'm using a route to create a PDF using meteor-pdfkit. Here is my current code which allows me to display my `Calendars` `ID` onto the PDF.

```
 Router.route('/calendars/:_id/getPDF', function() {
     var currentCalendar = this.params._id;
     var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 50});
     doc.fontSize(12);
     doc.text(currentCalendar, 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
     this.response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
         'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
     });
     this.response.end( doc.outputSync() );
 }, {where: 'server'});
```

However, when I try to include other information from the Calendars collection, the data comes back as undefined or creates an error. For example, if I try to call `curentCalendar.name`:

```
 Router.route('/calendars/:_id/getPDF', function() {
     var currentCalendar = this.params._id;
     var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 50});
     doc.fontSize(12);
     doc.text(currentCalendar.name, 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
     this.response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
         'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
     });
     this.response.end( doc.outputSync() );
 }, {where: 'server'});
```

I'm assuming this is because the route doesn't have access to the information from the collection. How do I allow the route to access the information from the Calendars collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `currentCalendar` is being set to an id. I think you want to write:

```
var currentCalendar = Calendars.findOnw(this.params._id);
```

Now `currentCalendar` will be a document with properties, e.g. `currentCalendar.name`.

Comment: So simple. I love it. Thanks David.

Answer (score 1):

`currentCalendar.name` is undefined because you are looking for a property `name` on the string `currentCalendar` which is nothing more than the id value supplied in the URL. Therefore, all it knows is a number.

What you would have to do is create some array with information about your calendars, ie:

`global.calendars = [{name: "Holidays", data: ...}, {name: "Tests", data: ...}]`

Then, in your route, you can then get the information based on the index as such:

`doc.text(calendars[currentCalendar].name, 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});`

Because now `calendars[currentCalendar].name` is defined

Comment: I'm assuming it would be fairly easy to include data from an existing Calendars collection instead of static arrays?

Comment: @JeremyE David's answer shows how to do it from the existing set.